# Download a file and update the current downloaded percentage

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, http

I am not a big fan of JS, but have been forced to use it in this situation for various reasons.

My task: Download a URL to a target file, and update another part of the application with the current percentage.

I've run jslint and jshint over the code, and it seems happy, but I am sure there is still plenty of suboptimal stuff in my code. My code currently looks like this:

```
Match.prototype.downloadURL = function (url, target, next) {
    winston.info("Downloading url %s to %s", url, target);
    var tmpFilename = target + ".tmp",
        tmpFile = fs.createWriteStream(tmpFilename);
    http.get(url, function (resp) {
        var fullSize = +resp.headers["Content-Length"],
            currentSize = 0,
            currentPercentage = -1;
        // Write the file
        resp.pipe(tmpFile);
        resp.on('end', function () {
            tmpFile.close();
            this.registerDownloadFinished();
            fs.rename(tmpFilename, target, function (err) {
                if (err !== null) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                next(null, target);
            });
        });
        // Update when we hit a new percentage
        resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
            currentSize += chunk.length;
            var percentage = parseInt(currentSize / fullSize * 100, 10);
            if (percentage === currentPercentage) {
                return;
            }
            currentPercentage = percentage;
            this.updateDownloadingPercentage(percentage);
        });
    });
};
```

Problems I can see:

1. `updateDownloadingPercentage` and `registerDownloadFinished` are networked operations; I should probably be doing something to make sure these things arrive in order
2. I have a feeling I should be checking for errors a lot more; `createWriteStream` can fail, so where do I get its error message from.

Again, I only ask because I am a very poor JavaScript coder.  Please enlighten me as to any way I can improve this snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over and reading some docs:

- You need a `resp.on('error', function () {}` to deal with http errors
- You need a `tmpFile.on('error', function () {}` to deal with fs/stream errors
- `tmpFile` is an unfortunate name, i would call it maybe `tmpStream` or `tmpFileStream`
- You use both single and double quotes for strings, stick to one, preferably single quotes
- `resp` should be `res` ( standard in Node ), or `response`, it bugs me every time I read the code ;)

Comment: Death to single quotes :) Thanks for this, makes sense. Of course, I now have additional questions, but at least my code is correct now.